# Transfer RubyMine settings to IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

I'm interested in upgrading from RubyMine 5 to the full IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 12. I'd like, however, to keep my RubyMine settings intact when making the transition.

Is it possible to transfer my RubyMine settings to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `File` | `Export Settings` and `File` | `Import Settings`. Not all the features can be transferred as RubyMine is just a subset of IDEA, but it should work for the most parts.